# webkit-line-clamp with text-align: justify;

Tags: javascript, css, text-align

I have an issue when using `line-clamp` on text that have the CSS prop `text-align: justify;` as you can see here: [Safari (mobile & desktop) and Chrome mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fthfv.png)

The 3 dots at the end of my text are overlapping the text. This happens on Safari (mobile & desktop) but not on Chrome desktop where it's working as expected:
[Chrome desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OMml.png)

However, it's also happens on Chrome mobile.

I don't really know why this happens, the only way I found to fix it is to use `text-align: left` instead of `text-align: justify` but this changes the display and I would like to keep `text-align: justify`.

Code:

```
<div className="pt-6 text-justify text-sm line-clamp-9">
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're using Chrome on iOS, you're using the same browsing engine as Safari; Apple doesn't allow competing browsing engines on iOS. Your code doesn't show the issue because it depends on CSS classes defined by a framework like Bootstrap. Please [edit] your question to include the version, and add its tag. It also appears you are using React, since you use `className="`, which is not valid HTML. Either amend your question to use `class="` or add the rest of the React code. We'd like a [mre] so that we can try out any advice we might give.